# POST curl returns bad request 400 (flask,RESTful)

Tags: python, post, flask

I have a problem posting JSON via curl.
I began to study the development of a web recently. I read guides from Miguel Grinberg, look up over all possible resources. I want to POST into json new field. 
If any parameter is missing in the request, then 400.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

DATA = {
    'id': 1111,
    'Label': {'0.5': 'letter'},
}

def abort_if_no_data(key):
    if key not in DATA:
        abort(404)

class Data(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()

    def get(self, key):
        abort_if_no_data(key)
        return DATA[key]

    def delete(self, key):
        del DATA[key]
        return '', 200

    def put(self, key):
        abort_if_no_data(key)
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        for key, value in args.items():
            DATA[key] = value

            return args, 200


class DataList(Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()

    def post(self):
        args = self.reqparse.parse_args()
        if args is not request.json:
            abort(400)
        for key, value in args.items():
            DATA[0] = {key: value}
            return DATA[key], 201

api.add_resource(DataList, '/test')
api.add_resource(Data, '/test/<key>')
```

So when I'm trying curl it with

```
curl -X POST --data '{"value": 41}' http://localhost:5000/test
```

Server answers with Bad Request 400

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request", 
    "status": 400
}
* Closing connection 0
```

I want to add a new field but I can't. What am I doing wrong and what I should do?

Comment: If you're just getting started with web development and the Flask framework, you should maybe take a look at some [easier examples](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/) first to understand the mechanics of Flask.

Comment: @Cipher, I read this quickstart-guide. Yes, it was easy, but there's the main problem: next step from easiest examples are "specific problems". And very often solutions for these problems resolved with many workarounds. And it doesn't help with understanding of some things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a bit of a limb here, but I'm going to assume that it's due to the fact that you're not specifying the Content-Type header in the cUrl request. Try adding `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to your cUrl command. Werkzeug's request objects likely don't default to json.

Comment: Well, I've tried with this string:
`curl -H "Content-Type=application/json" --data "{"label": 41}"  -X POST http://localhost:5000/test`
 but it doesn't work, still 400.

Comment: Sorry, "=" should be ":". Typo